# The asp:tableRow is not shown on browser (IE9 - asp.NET)

Tags: asp.net, row

```
<asp:table runat="server" ID="mainTable" Width="100%" Height="100%" BorderColor="Red" BorderWidth="20px" BorderStyle="Solid">
    <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="mainRow" Width="100%" Height="100%" BorderColor="Purple" BorderWidth="20px" BorderStyle="Solid">
        <asp:TableCell runat="server" ID="maincell" Width="100%" Height="100%" BorderColor="AliceBlue" BorderWidth="20px" BorderStyle="Solid">
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="mainpanel" Width="100px" Height="100px" BackColor="Gainsboro"></asp:Panel>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:table>
```

Why does the tablerow is not shown? 
I can see only a frame of RED, inside it a blue frame and inside it grey panel, where is the purple frame (the table row) between the red table and the blue cell?

Comment: i just tried your same code, it work fine in ie 7,8 and 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It because the row color is overridden by the cells. A table cell is a part of table row only.

Comment: can i make the table row visible ? i mean , make the cell not override the row entirely?

Comment: I am not sure if that can be done. But, you can surely set the border-bottom and border-top to none of ur cells. This way the row color will be shown